# conda команда не найдена

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook

Установил anaconda3 на Debian в режиме пользователя. Под пользователем всё работает хорошо. Под рутом выдает сообщение, что команда не найдена.

Почему так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, приложение не видно в переменной окружения [`PATH`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F)). Войдите в систему под пользователем, узнайте расположение приложения, например, так:

```
which conda
```

Далее под администратором добавьте папку с приложением в переменную окружения **PATH**.